# asp google maps

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I  want to visualize points using Google Maps and Asp.net.

1. visualize a map
2. put the points in the map
3. trace the path points

This is my current code.

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:80%; height:80%"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.781367900048, 6.6401992834884);
        var options = { zoom: 14, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
        var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker(optionsMarqueur);
        marqueur.bindTo(latlng, map, "center");
    }
    $(function () {
        initialize();
    }); 
</script>
```

But so I have the map without the marker. I'd like to know how can I change this code to visualize a path between two points. Thank you.

Comment: What version of the Google Maps API are you using? Version 2 or version 3? Also, where is `optionsMarqueur` defined and how?

Comment: version 3 and optionsMarqueur = options